# How to have a specific header for the home page?

Tags: cms, css, header

I would like to have specific css parameters for the header of the HomePage.
(a different height and some text displayed)

how can I do that?

(I tried creating a specific .css file and linked it to the homepage vis the CMS admin panel by adding

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addCss">
    <stylesheet>css/styles_home.css</stylesheet>
    <params>media="screen"</params>
</action>
```

the css file is loaded, but the general style.css is also applied and has the last word…)

thank you of your help

Comment: hi @Alexglvr, Marius is correct. can you try his solution and accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own style in the same `styles.css` file. Each page has a different class on the body. You can use that.
The homepage has the body class `cms_index_index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom css class only for the homepage, and create a new css rule only for this class.

```
<reference name="root">
  <action method="addBodyClass"><classname>myHomepageBodyClass</classname></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: where may I add this code? In the CMS panel?
could please tell me how to make a css rule for this class only?
thank you for your help.

Comment: yes, you can add this xml code in magento backend, when editing the cms page, tab layout. 
.myHomepageBodyClass {
  margin-top:100px; // css rules
}

Answer (score 0):

If you want css from cms admin then goto admin it cms page content tab click on Show/Hidden tab add below code on page code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{skin url='css/my.css'}}" />
```

Comment: I tried adding another modification (texted displayed) and now it is not working any more…
I tried stepping back… still not working…
what is strange, is when you go back to the homepage content in the CMS admin panel, the added line is automatically removed..

Comment: I found the problem : (I am changing the header height.)
At the first test, when it worked, I was having a general height for testing. After i commented it because I have different height regarding the windows size :
 @include bp(min-width, $bp-large + 1) {
 .main-header {
  height: 37em;
 }}
...
and that is what is not working...

Comment: I then just changed it with the compiled version (found in style.css) :
@media only screen and (min-width: 1051px) {
  .main-header {
    height: 37em;
  }
}
working like a charm !

Comment: That option can be easily removed by someone in Administrator Panel without knowledge about coding. Definetly not a good option.

Comment: i know  about it...

Comment: and @marius Answer is too good